# Product of Different Diagonal Entries in Positive Definite Matrix Exceeds Product of Different Off-Diagonal Entries.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

I am currently battling with a problem involving positive definite matrices and I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Let $A$ be a positive definite, though not necessarily symmetric, matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. I am trying to prove the inequality $a_{ii} \cdot a_{jj} > a_{ij} \cdot a_{ji}$ $\forall i \neq j$.

From the definition of positive definiteness, I understand that for all non-zero vectors $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $x^T A x > 0$.

I have attempted to use this property by considering $a_{ii} \cdot a_{jj} > a_{ij} \cdot a_{ji}$ $\iff$ $e_{i}^T A e_{i} \cdot e_{j}^T A e_{j}$ > $e_{i}^T A e_{j} \cdot e_{j}^T A e_{i}$ and aiming to simplify, but my efforts have been unsuccessful so far.

I would be grateful for any hints, insights, or proofs to guide me through this challenge.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Consider $p(x)=(xe_i+e_j)^TA(xe_i+e_j)$. It is a quadratic polynomial in $x$. Since $p(x)>0$ for all real $x$, the discriminant of $p$ must be negative...

Comment: @user1551 I think that would work in the case that A is symmetric, but it doesn't have to  since A isn't necessarily symmetric.

Comment: It still works when $A$ is non-symmetric. By considering $p$ one may infer that $a_{ii}a_{jj}$ is strictly greater than $\left(\frac{a_{ij}+a_{ji}}{2}\right)^2$ and the latter is $\ge a_{ij}a_{ji}$.

Comment: @user1551 Oh you are right! Thank you so much! <3